# Getting error in Robot Framework driver (The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver)

Tags: testing, robotframework

I have created the following java class:

```
public class setup {    
    public void browserSetup() {
      // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/cangouser-38/Documents/mohan/chromedriver");
}
```

my robot framework test case looks like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  A resource file containing the application specific keywords
Library     Selenium2Library
Library     com.Auto.Robot.SeleniumRobot.setup

*** Test Cases ***
Check out joe colantonio dot com
    Open Browser  https://www.google.com  gc
    Close Browser
```

The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

chromedriver.**exe** :-)

My setup with my own Chrome profile:

```
// path to chromedriver.exe    
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");

// new instace of ChromeOptions
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

// add arg to load Chrome with my own profile instead of a temporary profile
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\pburgr\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");

// new instance of ChromeDriver with added args
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

// maximaze current window, can be used later again if window get minimaze or after a new window is opened (in Chrome no switch is needed)
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: OP's environment is *nix - check the path that's provided, and the question is in the context of Robotframework - not the vanilla java+webdriver selenium.